# saving path in database with html/php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, filepath

I'm developing a database using Postgresql, PHP and Javascript. The database will be in the same machine along with other files (such as images, videos, etc). The users will use the browser to see, edit and enter information. I need the users to be able to store a file location (relative path+name) in the database, so when reading the tables, with one click they can open the file again. I tried using

```
<input type='file'...
```

but this don't show the path (for security reasons, I know), so it's useless for this. Does anybody know a way to do that, that is not going to Nautilus (it's an Ubuntu machine), and copy/paste the file name and folder? (This would take too long for many files. And sometimes I want to save only a path...) Thank you!

Comment: im a little confused, by saving the path, are YOU defining the path in the back-end? you could just make a path column in the DB and call it from there.

Comment: why would you need the path on the USER'S machine?  You should only care about the path on the SERVER.

Comment: Server and User machine is the same in this case. The files are all spread out in many different folders, and the user, who will fill the db, will say where are some critical files. I wanna store the full filename in the database, so the user get quick access to it later.

Comment: I've just found that I can do a ctrl+c inside Nautilus and a ctrl+v in the <input type='text'...> and it copies the full path and filename, ready to be saved in the db. But I thought it would be possible from inside the browser alone.

Comment: Local filesystem paths are not generally relevant to web pages, so they're not exposed to Javascript. (In part because they may contain sensitive information, like the user's name.)